# How to shorter code for weather api?

Tags: api, weather

How could I shorter this part of the code and instead of putting all options append weather icons for all possible situations?

```
 if (desc == "clear sky")
{
  $('div.clear').removeClass('hide'); 
} else if (desc == "broken clouds")
  {
    $('div.cloudy').removeClass('hide');
  }
 else if (desc == "few clouds")
  {
    $('div.cloudy').removeClass('hide');
  }
```

and so on...

```
 else {
  $('#desc').text("now it's ");
}
```

Comment: Note: I think that this question would make more sense on the [code review stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`switch/case`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) statement which would look like this

```
 switch(desc)
  {
    case "clear sky":
     $('div.clear').removeClass('hide');
    break;
    case "broken clouds":
     $('div.cloudy').removeClass('hide');
    break;
    case "few clouds":
     $('div.cloudy').removeClass('hide');
    break;
    case default:
     $('#desc').text("now it's ");
    break;
  }
```

An other option would be to make a dictionary where the key is the `case` and the value is a function to execute.